# Can I fix phone number formatting in my database using an update query in Coldfusion?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a customer table (customer_table) in my database that has a cell phone column (cell_phone). Before I had input masking implemented in my HTML form, the values were being entered in the database without any standard formatting mask.

Here is an example of some data:

Customer_A: 7325555555

Customer_B: 1732-555-5555

Customer_C: +17325555555

Customer_D: 1-732-555-5555

Customer_E: 732-555-5555

I want to fix all this data and have all the numbers follow this format: 732-555-5555

Is there a way to run an update query on this table and add the hyphens and strip the proceeding '1' for the data in the column that need updating?

Comment: Is there a reason you're not storing normalized E.164 phone-numbers in your database instead? Storing formatted numbers never ends well...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a regular expression to strip any non-digits, use the rightmost 10 characters of the result and build the new phone number by concatenating substrings and hyphens:

```
UPDATE customer 
 INNER JOIN (SELECT id, right(regexp_replace(phone, '[^0-9]', ''), 10) as phone 
               FROM customer) c 
    ON customer.id = c.id
   SET customer.phone = concat(substr(c.phone, 1, 3), '-',
                               substr(c.phone, 4, 3), '-',
                               substr(c.phone, 7));
```

Here's a [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/pjvTmIDx)

Comment: Upvoted, but last line should be: `substr(c.phone, 7));`

Comment: Yes, those who can calculate 4+3 are at a clear advantage :-) I'll fix this.

Comment: @Mihe That seemed to do the trick. Thank you.